# PC Shutting Down Without Warning

Tags: troubleshooting, power-supply-unit, desktop

I have a Windows 7 PC that is shutting down without warning, seemingly at random.  Here are the symptoms and notes:

- PC seemingly turns off completely.  After taking off the cover it turns out the fans continue to run after this happens.
- After this happens, the power button light turns and stays orange (it is white while running and dark while powered down).  I can't restart the machine without unplugging it and plugging it back in.
- No warning messages of any kind.  When I have had overheated PCs in the past, I have usually seen a heat-related warning message.
- Happened so far when browsing the internet, while idling, while booting, while running a diagnostic test (the one at start-up that is built into Windows).
- Fans seems to work fine.
- I ran a thermal test program on the box, and the highest readings I saw were GPU (68C) and "temp3" (62C).  I have no idea what "temp3" represents.
- No changes have been made to the PC recently (software or hardware), outside of a minor move (really just sliding it about 3 feet a few days ago).

I realize that this is impossible to really diagnose via ServerFault--I am looking for help in steps I can take to diagnose the problem (programs I can run, etc.).

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly a hardware problem. Get a diagnostic tool from your vendor and run it through. If you cannot get something like this, at least run something like memtest provided by most Linux versions, which you can run by getting a lived. If it is in warranty, it is best to ask for vendor  service.